# Indexing content of PDF files in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, pdf

Is the content of not converted PDF files, stored in Google Drive, indexed?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "not converted" but [Google does index PDF Files](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35287).

> Google can index the content of most
>   types of pages and files. The most
>   common file types we index include:
>
> - Adobe Flash (.swf)
> - Adobe PortableDocument Format (.pdf)
> - AdobePostScript (.ps)
> - Autodesk Design Web Format (.dwf)
> - Basic source code (.bas)
> - C/C++ source code (.c, .cc, .cpp, .cxx, .h, .hpp)
> - Google Earth (.kml, .kmz)
> - GPS eXchange Format (.gpx)
> - Hancom Hanword (.hwp)
> - HTML (.htm, .html)
> - Java source code (.java)
> - Microsoft Excel (.xls, .xlsx)
> - Microsoft PowerPoint (.ppt, .pptx)
> - Microsoft Word (.doc, .docx)
> - OpenOffice presentations (.odp)
> - OpenOffice spreadsheet (.ods)
> - OpenOffice text (.odt)
> - Perl source code (.pl)
> - Python source code (.py)
> - Rich Text Format (.rtf, .wri)
> - Scalable Vector Graphics (.svg)
> - Text (.ans, .asc, .cas, .txt, .text)
> - Wireless Markup Language (.wml, .wap)
> - XML (.xml)

Answer (score 1):

If a PDF is a scanned image, e.g. you scan a copy of your water utility bill and you save this doc into Drive, it will not be indexed, or appear in searches.